# php mysql join multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table

User

```
userID username     email
  1       abc    abc@abc.com
  2       def    def@def.com
  3       ghi    ghi@ghi.com
```

Referral

```
 refID userID      invEmail
   1      1      abc@def.com
   2      1      omg@mog.com
   3      1      def@def.com
```

So what i plan is to give a `invited user 5 point` meanwhile a `inviter 10 point`, so basically `userID 1` gained 30 meanwhile `userID 2` gained 5. The point i can do in PHP but one part i faced difficulty is when a invEmail to be identified. I don't mind separating into multiple queries if its will work.

How do i show this in sql?

I tried something like

```
SELECT *, count(r.userID) FROM user u, referral r WHERE u.userID = r.userID OR u.email = r.invEmail GROUP BY r.userID
```

It returned wrong value.

**What i would like it to return**, how much count is there inviter and invitee(matched email who has registered based on inviter invitation)

How should i do it?

Thank you.

Edit: i forgot to add something into question, what if i wanted the inviter to receive 10 points only if invitee registered? what i meant is that, only if invEmail exists in u.email then only userID received 10 point. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include A) what it is returning, and B) what you would like it to return?

Comment: ok edited to add what should be returned

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do something like this:

```
select points.userId, points.username, points.email, sum(points.points)
FROM
(select u.*, count(*)*10 as points
  from user u
    join referral on u.userID = r.userID
    join user verify_user on r.invEmail = verify_user.email
  group by u.userID, u.username, u.email
UNION
select u.*, count(*)*5 as points
  from user u
    join referral on u.email = r.invEmail and u.userID != r.userID
  group by u.userID, u.username, u.email
) as points
group by points.userId, points.username, points.email
```

I think you need two separate selects to get the points for each type of registration, combined with a union statement.

Comment: Wow certainly out of my league, i am trying this solution and will let you know soon. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: may i know what this meant? `join referral on u.userID = r.refID and u.userID != r.userID` as refID is just primary key increasing with auto increment

Comment: sql `FROM` is missing from query

Comment: I need more coffee this morning

Comment: Hi, i forgot to add something into question, what if i wanted the inviter to receive 10 points only if invitee registered? what i meant is that, only if invEmail exists in u.email then only userID received 10 point. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: I've added in a check on the first part of the union query to make sure that the invited user exists.

Comment: Thank you very much. May god bless you. Brilliant Solution.